# Weird problem $z^i=i$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Weird problem $z^i=i$:

$$i\ln z=i$$

Then:

$$\ln z=1$$

Therefore:

$$e^1=z\implies z=\cos(1)+i\sin(1)$$ is that right?

I was told it's not.

Comment: is this the right place?

Comment: should not the first equation be $i \ln z = \ln i = i\pi/2?$  do you have other account/s here?

Comment: @abel Other accounts?

Comment: @abel Yes that was my mistake

Comment: @Abel Did someone already ask this?>

Comment: i am just curious if you used to be committing to a challenge.

Comment: @abel committed to a challenge? Is that a user or a game?

Comment: @abel I just choose my name based on a game at uni if that is what you are asking?

Comment: let us not worry about this any more. i am good.

Comment: @abel can you explain? Is this a new user thing? I don't know the procedures yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take the main argument for complex numbers: $\;-\pi<\arg z\le \pi\;$ (and thus you have the usual branch cut for the complex logarithm, i.e. the non-positive real axis is out), then:

$$z^i=i\implies i\log z=\log i=\frac\pi2i\implies\log z=\frac\pi2\implies z=e^{\frac\pi2}$$

Comment: I see , I didn't know that $\log(i)=\frac{i\pi}{2}$!

actually why is that?

Comment: @Max Inh fact it is $$\log i=\log|i|+i\arg(i)=0+i\left(\frac\pi2+2k\pi\right)\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z$$ but if the principal value of the argument is chosen then we get $\;k=0\;$  above.

Comment: Is that true in general? E.g. $\log z = \log|z| + i \arg(z)$?

Comment: Or Is it $\log(Im Z) = \log|Im z| + i\arg(Im z)$?

Comment: @MaxedTag Both the imaginary and the real parts of a complex numbers are *real numbers*, so in your last comment you're asking about the logarithm of a real number, which by the way **has** to be positive. The *definition* is what you ask two comments above.